# what is impex file?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

could any body explain the fields macros, headers, data, and bean shell in .impex file?
what are the symbols like #,$ meaning in .impex file?
what is the difference between .impEx and .imPex?

Answer (score 4):

- # Is a comment
- $ has several meanings (depending on context)
- The file extension is irrelevant, it doesn't even need to be **.impex**

You should read the impex documentation. It is very well documented.

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+Syntax

Answer (score 1):

**Impex** files uses Comma-Separated Values, it allows for exemple creating, updating, removing  items.

**$** Macro definitions for exemple **$namemacro=name1** each time we have **namemacro** in the impex file, it is replaced by **name1**.

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Importing+and+Exporting

Answer (score 0):

ImpEx is an integrated text-based import/export extension for creating, updating, removing, and exporting platform items.

For Example, I've created a demo project named training in which I can add product catalog by importing this ImpEx

$productCatalog=trainingProductCatalog
$classificationCatalog=trainingClassification
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]
$languages=ja,en,de,zh

## Product catalog

INSERT_UPDATE Catalog;id[unique=true]
;$productCatalog